# Pandas query for byte string literal on Linux results in AttributeError ... no attribute 'visit_Bytes'

Tags: python, linux, pandas

I'm trying to write a pandas query for a byte string literal.  This works OK on Windows, but I get an exception on Red Hat Ent. Linux.  Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, b'3'], [4, 5, b'6'], [7, 8, b'9']],
              columns=['num1', 'num2', 'byteStr'])
print(df)
print()
df_qnum = df.query("num1 == 1")
print(df_qnum)
print()
df_qstr = df.query("byteStr == b'6'")
print(df_qstr)
```

Windows results:

```
   num1  num2 byteStr
   0     1     2    b'3'
   1     4     5    b'6'
   2     7     8    b'9'

   num1  num2 byteStr
   0     1     2    b'3'

   num1  num2 byteStr
   1     4     5    b'6'
```

Linux results:

```
   num1  num2 byteStr
   0     1     2    b'3'
   1     4     5    b'6'
   2     7     8    b'9'

   num1  num2 byteStr
   0     1     2    b'3'

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "pandasTest.py", line 10, in <module>
     df_qstr = df.query("byteStr == b'6'")
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3231, in query
     res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)
   ...
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 374, in    visit
     visitor = getattr(self, method)
   AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Bytes'
```

How can I get this query to work in Linux?  Have tried on Python3 and Pandas 1.0.1 and 1.1.4.

Answer (score 1):

You can always decode `byte objects` to literal strings and then `query`, like this:

```
In [4516]: df.byteStr = df.byteStr.str.decode("utf-8")

In [4517]: df
Out[4517]: 
   num1  num2 byteStr
0     1     2       3
1     4     5       6
2     7     8       9

In [4519]: df.query("byteStr == '6'")
Out[4519]: 
   num1  num2 byteStr
1     4     5       6
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid the conversion as this runs on a wide variety of HDF5 files and some of the datasets are pretty large and it takes a while to run.  Ideally, I can just query as is.  I'll need to do a few experiments to see what the impacts are in the general solution.